# Passing additional data value to strongly typed partial views in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-binding, partial-views

I have an `OrderForm` domain class, which has property subclasses, something like:

```
interface IOrderForm
{
    int OrderId { get; }

    ICustomerDetails CustomerDetails { get; set; }
    IDeliveryDetails DeliveryDetails{ get; set; }
    IPaymentsDetails PaymentsDetails { get; set; }
    IOrderDetails OrderDetails { get; set; } 
}
```

My "Details" view is strongly typed inheriting from `IOrderForm`. I then have a strongly type partial for rendering each section:

```
<div id="CustomerDetails">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("CustomerDetails", Model.CustomerDetails); %>
</div>

<div id="DeliveryDetails">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("DeliveryDetails", Model.DeliveryDetails); %>
</div>

... etc
```

This works ok up to this point, but I'm trying to add some nice ajax bits for updating some parts of the order form, and I've realised that each of my partial views also needs access to the `IOrderForm.OrderId`.

Whats the easiest way to give my partials access to this value?

Comment: Do you have your orderId in your route, simply take it from there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the value from your Route using something like

```
this.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString["OrderId"]
```

Or your add it to your viewData and reuse pass it to your partialView

TempData is also a pretty simple way...

Answer (score 2):

You would have to change your code a bit but you could do this

```
<div id="CustomerDetails"> 
    <% Html.RenderPartial("CustomerDetails", new {OrderID = Model.OrderID,  CustomerDetails = Model.CustomerDetails}); %> 
</div> 

<div id="DeliveryDetails"> 
    <% Html.RenderPartial("DeliveryDetails", new {OrderID = Model.OrderID, DeliveryDetails = Model.DeliveryDetails); %> 
</div>
```

Or you could assign the OrderID to tempData in the Action

```
TempData("OrderId") = your orderIDValue
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload for `RenderPartial` that accepts both a Model object and a ViewData dictionary, so potentially you could just set a ViewData value, and pass the ViewData object to the partial.

Another option is to include an Order Id member in your partial ViewModel, and copy the Order Id to it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply depend on a Model for RenderPartial, simply pass your model through.

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/controls/users.ascx", modelGoesHere); %>
```

then inside the partial view itself, normally you could do the following:

```
<%= Model.VariableName %>
```